# Why does the keyboard dismiss when an item is added to this LazyVerticalGrid?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

This is a simplified version of my code that reproduces the issue. Notice that when you tap on the button, an item is added to the list of items in the LazyVerticalGrid. If you tap on this button while the keyboard is up, it dismisses the keyboard. How can I stop the keyboard from dismissing? Or is there another way to set up the OutlinedTextField so it is outside of the LazyVerticalGrid? One requirement is that the OutlinedTextField must scroll with the items in the LazyVerticalGrid.

See a screen recording here. https://imgur.com/a/1hKBcyg

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import androidx.compose.material3.Surface
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import chenige.chkchk.wairz.theme.AppTheme
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.height
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridCells
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.GridItemSpan
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.grid.LazyVerticalGrid
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.OutlinedTextField
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp

class TestFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var composeView: ComposeView
    private var listOfImages = mutableStateListOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        return ComposeView(requireContext()).also {
            composeView = it
        }
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        composeView.setContent {
            AppTheme {
                Surface {
                    TestScreen(list = listOfImages, addItem = { listOfImages.add("New") })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestScreen(
    list: List<String>,
    addItem: () -> Unit,
) {

    LazyVerticalGrid(
        columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
        content = {

            items(list.size) {
                Text(
                    text = list[it], modifier = Modifier
                        .fillMaxSize()
                        .height(150.dp)
                        .background(
                            Color.Gray
                        )
                )
            }

            item(span = {
                GridItemSpan(maxLineSpan)
            }) {

                Column(
                    Modifier
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .padding(16.dp)) {
                    OutlinedTextField(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                        value = "Text",
                        onValueChange = { text ->
                        }
                    )

                    Button(
                        onClick = { addItem.invoke() },
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                    ) {
                        Text("Add another item")
                    }
                }

            }
        })


}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun TestScreenPreview() {
    AppTheme {
        TestScreen(list = listOf("1", "2", "3", "4", "5")) {
        }
    }
}
```